# Spinner drop down setOnItemSelectedListener not working- android

Tags: android, events, spinner

Hey Everyone so I have been trying to get this spinner hooked up but it won't call the onItemSelected listener. Here is what I keep seeing on SO and every tute but nothing is working.

***************** Code

```
 public class QuoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

public Spinner mCountrySpinner;
public Spinner mStateSpinner;
public Spinner mCitySpinner;
public Spinner mPayPointSpinner;
public Spinner mDeliveryCurrencySpinner;

public ArrayList<String> mCountryOptions = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mStateOptions = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mCityOptions = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mPayPointOptions = new ArrayList<>();
public ArrayList<String> mDeliveryCurrencyOptions = new ArrayList<>();

public String mSelectedCountry;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quote);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle(R.string.Calculate_a_Quote);

    mCountrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
    mStateSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.state_province_spinner);
    mCitySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.city_spinner);
    mPayPointSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.pay_point_spinner);
    mDeliveryCurrencySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.delivery_currency_spinner);

    mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    populateSpinnerData(WebApiManager.FAKE_AGENT_ID);
}

@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quote, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home: // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        case R.id.quote_action:
            Toast.makeText(this, "TODO: Get Quote", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void populateSpinnerData(String agentID){

    getPayPointApiInfo(agentID, Utility.payPointDataType.countryType.toString(), null);

    ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mCountryOptions);
    mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
}

private void convertData(JSONObject data,String dataType) {
    try {
        String status = data.getString(WebApiManager.KEY_STATUS);
        if (status.equals("Ok")) {
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.countryType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mCountryOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.stateType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mStateOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.cityType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mCityOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.payPointType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mPayPointOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.deliveryCurrencyType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mDeliveryCurrencyOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("PendingQueue", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
        Log.i("PendingQueue", jse.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

public void getPayPointApiInfo(String agentID, final String type, String country) {

    WebApiManager.getPayPointInfo(this, agentID, type, country, new WebApiManager.OnResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Response = " + response.toString());
            convertData(response, type);
        }
    }, new WebApiManager.OnErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error");
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(QuoteActivity.this)
                    .setMessage(error.getCause().getMessage())
                    .setTitle(R.string.app_name)
                    .create();
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
```

**********XML

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/country_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="15dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/country_title_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="Country"/>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/country_spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

What am I doing wrong here ??

Comment: Could you paste all of your class code?

Comment: Which spinner are you testing?  You have five spinners, and only set the listener for one of them....

Comment: I am only testing the first one just to get something working before add listeners to the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally found the answer to this issue. The problem was with the fact that the data is populated by a web call to the api in getPayPointApiInfo(). Since I was assigning the spinner to the empty array list before the web request was completed the listener was not being called. So i just needed to put :)

```
private void convertData(JSONObject data,String dataType) {
    try {
        String status = data.getString(WebApiManager.KEY_STATUS);
        if (status.equals("Ok")) {
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.countryType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mCountryOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
    ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,mCountryOptions);
    mCountrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.stateType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mStateOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.cityType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mCityOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.payPointType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mPayPointOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
            if(dataType.equalsIgnoreCase(Utility.payPointDataType.deliveryCurrencyType.toString())){
                JSONArray info = data.getJSONArray(WebApiManager.KEY_CAPITAL_RESULT);
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length();i++){
                    JSONObject row = info.getJSONObject(i);
                    if(row != null)
                        mDeliveryCurrencyOptions.add(row.getString("value"));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.i("PendingQueue", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    } catch (JsonSyntaxException jse) {
        Log.i("PendingQueue", jse.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try to use it:

```
    mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "test "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I have tried this and every variation of on Item selected listener it still does not get called.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You can't click on Spinner? You click on Spinner but it is not develop? It develop but after click on some position nothings happened?

Comment: The on item selected listener is not called after selecting an item.

Comment: Nope neither callback its invoked at all.

Comment: Maybe you should try to put your data at Spinner and then just call mCountrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: Tried that as well with no luck :(.